# Getting connection closed error in ADF when connecting with azure SQL after few mins

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-sql

I have an error that occurs in my Azure data factory Data Flow that shows up during a trigger run . I have a data flow where the source is an Azure storage account. After formatting data we sink it to Azure SQL tables. I've done data preview from end to end, and the transformations work fine. I processed the data end to end on a debug run , it works for couple of hours before giving below error. However, when I run a event trigger, the data flow always fails around ~10 mins in with the following error:

Operation on target [Dataflow_Name_Here] failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"The connection is closed.","Details":"The connection is closed."}

I get Test connection succeeded message when checking if all linked services are up. Is there any user configuration that needs to be fixed for keeping database connection alive? How we can fix it

Anyone faced such issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned since the failure happens after couple of hours , i think you are facing a capacity issue on the SQL side . Which tier are you using is it S0 ? Do you think we can upgrade the tier and see if that helps ?